# Why can't I enumerate object property defined as not enumerable?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the object properties that were defined via `Object.defineProperty` method.

> ### [`Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
>
> The `Object.defineProperty()` method defines a new property directly on an object, or modifies an existing property on an object, and returns the object.
>
> - `obj` - The object on which to define the property.
> - `prop` - The name of the property to be defined or modified.
> - `descriptor`: The descriptor for the property being defined or modified.

So, let's take an example:

```
> a = {}
{}
> a.foo = "bar"
'bar'
> Object.keys(a)
[ 'foo' ]
> Object.defineProperty(a, "bar", { get: function () { return "foo"; }})
{ foo: 'bar' }
> a.bar
'foo'
> a.foo
'bar'
> Object.keys(a)
[ 'foo' ]
> for (k in a) { console.log(k); }
foo
```

In the for loop thing, how can I list the `bar` property (that was defined with `defineProperty` function?

Comment: I suppose this is covered very well, in MDN itself

Comment: @thefourtheye True, I was a victim of [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) again. After writing my question I found the answer.. Decided to share the information with the other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your question *and* your answer can be improved :

Your question is either :

- How can i define an enumerable property using `Object.defineProperty` ?

Answer : by setting, in the property parameters `enumerable:true`

OR

- How can i retrieve a property that was defined on an object as non enumerable ?

Answer : by using  `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, which will perform quite like `keys`, except... all *own* properties are returned, meaning : *including* the non-enumerable properties but *not including* prototype's properties (and obviously, no properties from the prototype chain).

Comment: Thanks for `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` thing.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `enumerable` to `true`, will make it an `enumerable` property:

```
> Object.defineProperty(a, "b", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return "foo"; }})
{ foo: 'bar', b: [Getter] }
> for (k in a) { console.log(k); }
foo
b
> Object.keys(a)
[ 'foo', 'b' ]
```

> [`enumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description)
>
> `true` if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.
>
> Defaults to `false`.

Comment: Is it possible to get reversal for self-answer, don't you know? Maybe try?

Comment: @nicael Yeah, maybe. However, I cannot understand why the question is downvoted...

Comment: not sure but you can use @GameAlchemist suggestion for your question